# Is an incorrect address on a W2 a problem?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I worked at a company in 2011, with address A, and in 2012, came back to the Company with Address B. There were no overlaps with the addresses from 2011 to 2012. However, payroll didn't update my address when I came back in 2012. So basically, 100% of my income earned in 2012 was at Address B, but my W2 lists Address A. Is this going to be a problem on my taxes, or will it raise an Audit flag in the future? If so, is it possible to correct a W2, or is the printed one final?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a corrected W2 because the address is wrong. No-one cares about the address, its just where the form is being mailed to.

Re the tax calculations, since W2 is a summary of payments already done, if your withholding was incorrect because the employer thought you're in State A, but you're really in State B (county, city, whatever) - then its **your** problem to fix. The employer will not retroactively pay taxes on your behalf, and it is your responsibility to update the address when it changes. So if this is the case, calculate the taxes due and pay ASAP to the entity you should be paying, and file a claim for refund to the entity you shouldn't be paying. You may get hit with penalties. Ask the payroll if they can help you with this, but they probably won't. If they don't - no need to correct W2. Corrected W2 is a problem for the payroll, and makes a lot of additional significant work. They won't do it unless they *have to*.

If you're within the same tax jurisdiction, just moved a couple of blocks away - no-one cares.

Answer (score 2):

If both addresses are in the same state (Ohio?), there should be no problem with Federal income tax or state income tax as long as the taxpayer ID is correct. There might be 
issues with county income tax or city income tax, if any, and especially if the
tax withholding for these is incorrect. But, assuming these nonFederal
issues are not relevant, you could *ask* your payroll office about
issuing a corrected W-2 but they might drag their feet on the matter since it will mean
work for them (and expense to the company) without any effect on the substantive issues.
You *should*, of course, insist on them correcting your address in your files (for the
2013 W-2).